# Play framework 2.2.1 404 page

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Yes, there are already dozen of questions about that. However, everyone seems to ommit some important part. When I try the following code in my Global object,

```
public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
    return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
        views.html.notFoundPage.render(request.uri())
    ));
}
```

I get `error: cannot find symbol` on `pure(notFound(` .

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the you have imported the right classes.

Hope it help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears the syntax in my post was correct. I also do not know why, but see documentation here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaGlobal , also checked it and it did not work (Object cannot be resolved to a variable)

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, and 'Promise.<SimpleResult>pure' is not allowed in Java (if you look in the API, pure is a method of static class Promise, so till now what i said is ok). The last error you get is because you are using an 'Object' that is not defined yet. Try breaking the line into multiple lines to see what object is not defined.

Comment: "Promise" cannot be resolved to a variable, SimpleResult cannot be resolved to a variable, and then syntax error on '.' .

Comment: Try _return F.Promise.pure((SimpleResult)notFound(
        views.html.notFoundPage.render(request.uri())
    ));_ also

Comment: That sounds like you haven't imported the classes.

Comment: The `Promise.<SimpleResult>` is found correctly by compiler. Also it is present in all discussions about the subject

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45459/discussion-between-andrei-and-xyzk)